# How do I Supply Complex Runtime Parameters to Tomcat?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, configuration, jsf-2, tomcat6

I'm writing a JSF 2.1 web application, which is hosted by Tomcat 6.

At runtime, I'd like to retrieve a set of complex parameters related to external services.

At development time, I don't know what these parameters will be or how may there'll be.

The parameters will be set by our operations staff, and must therefore be defined outside of the .war file.

I thought that context.xml would help (i.e. `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/MyWebApp.xml`) but this can only accept scalar parameters, and there doesn't seem to be any way I can iterate over them.

Here is an example of what I'd like to access at runtime.

```
<services>
    <service id="bbc" name="BBC Weather" url="http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/" />

    <service id="underground" name="Weather Underground" url="http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/">
        <login username="test" password="test" />
    </service>

    <service id="network" name="The Weather Network" url="http://www.theweathernetwork.com/">
        <method type="post" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Is there a foolproof way I can programatically gain access to `TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/MyWebApp.xml`?  I know [how to get the path to TOMCAT_HOME](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-tomcat-home-directory-in-java/), but our operations guys may choose to change the Tomcat host or engine name.

As a workaround, I can always write a single parameter to context.xml as follows.

```
<Parameter name="config.file" value="C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 6.0/conf/Catalina/localhost/MyConfigFile.xml" />
```

But this is also an extra point of error, an extra step in the install instructions, needs to be maintained etc.

I'm sure there must be an easy way to do this, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance, Adam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own XML file and put it in one of the existing paths covered by Tomcat's default runtime classpath such as `Tomcat/lib`, or add its path to the runtime classpath by specifying it in `shared.loader` property of Tomcat's `/conf/catalina.properties`.

Once it's in the classpath, you can just obtain it through the classloader.

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = loader.getResourceAsStream("services.xml");
// ...
```